# How to get URL images from db server using field database in Ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using ireport 3.7.6. i have field images in the databases.i want to use the field images to display the images from server. When i put $F{images} in images expression. The images not appear in my report.

Anyone know about this?. Please help me.:(:(

Answer (score 0):

set field type to java.io.InputStream
and image expression type to java.awt.Image it will work..